# Whitelist users in Auth0

Tags: auth0, auth0-js

I've created an app that uses Auth0 for login. I have google-oauth2 enabled for the app. What I would like to do is have a whitelist of approved users who can login but all I see is a Users page where I can block users after they've logged in. Is there a way I can configure Auth0 to restrict Google users (and all users except approved ones). Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options that you could use in order to implement what you want:

- Using Auth0 Rules. Maybe you can try to create a Rule that check the user's email adress against a whitelist of adresses, and allow only access if the adress exists on the list. [Rules docs](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/rules/create-rules)
- Using Auth0 Client Grants. It will allow you to grant access to specific users, based on their userId. [Grant Types](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/applications/application-grant-types)
- Probably you could try to create a Group and assign users to that group and allow just them to log in or using auth0's connection .
- You could try to use that method based on email invitation too [Email invitation](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/email/send-email-invitations-for-application-signup)

Comment: Thanks.  I did your first suggestions. Quick followup. I don't need to copy that rule script into my code, that is what Auth0 runs on a user login from their server, correct?

Comment: Hello @Alan . You're right. You don't need to copy it in your code, as it runs on Auth0 server.